# Highlight a cell if the value is greater than the value of the cell from the preceding column

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, libreoffice-calc

Here is the dataset I am working on.

[image]

I want to highlight the transition from 0 to 1 and from 1 to 0.

So a cell should be red if the value of the cell is 1 and the preceding column cell has the value 0. And green when the cell is 0 and the preceding column cell has the value 1

Basically

```
Transiiton => Color   
0 -> 1 => 1 should be Green  
1 -> 0 => 0 should be Red
```

Comment: According to your description, shouldn't the transition rule be: `0 -> 1 => 1 should be **Red**` and `1 -> 0 => 0 should be **Green** ` ?

Comment: @tohuwawohu I think my description was a little confusing.  "0 -> 1 => 1 should be **Green**" is what I wanted. But nevermind, it's a small detail. The conditions worked and I just switched the colors. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select A2:J8 (since i assume that the cells in row 1 shouldn't get formatted);
2. Menu Format -> Conditional -> Condition...
3. Define two conditions (add the second using <kbd>Add</kbd> button after defining the first one):

   1. Cell value -> Is greater than -> A1

      Apply Style: Bad (gives dark red font color on light red background) or your own cell style
   2. Cell value -> Is lesser than -> A1

      Apply Style: Good (gives dark green font color on light green background) or your own cell style.

Notice that Calc will automatically *adapt the cell reference "A1" for all cells in range accordingly*. Thus, LO Calc will check the condition for cell B3 against B2 instead of A1.

Result:

[image]